# Elliptic threefolds with infinitely many sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there complex projective elliptic threefolds $f: X \to S$ with infinitely many rational sections satisfying the following properties?

- $S$ is a smooth surface of Picard rank $1$.
- $X$ is smooth with $q(X) = 0$. (Bonus: $\kappa(X) \ge 0$.)
- The discriminant locus of $f$ in $S$ is smooth.

If we drop any of the conditions above, there are examples of such elliptic threefolds.

Comment: The last condition is pretty strong. It implies the singular fibers are equisingular I suppose. Do you know any example such that the last condition holds and does not come from taking fiber product of an elliptic surface with a trivial family?